# Create CSS like Zoho CRM forms

Tags: css

Kindly go through the link and let me know how to create forms like Zoho CRM.
Can it be done using CSS?
https://crm.zoho.com/crm/CreateEntity.do?module=Contacts
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: You mean Design of form?

Comment: @Ani: I just started to create form and need to design like Zoho.

Comment: @chiragsolanki: Yes Chirag, I am talking about design of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you were asking like text-out method, and here is the way to get it..

Html:

```
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="inputText" required/>
    <span class="floating-label">Your email address</span>
  </div>
```

Css:

```
input:focus ~ .floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label{
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 6px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
```